# Visual Studio debugging issues after windows 10 update

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2017

Windows 10 has installed updates today and now for some reason Visual Studio is horrendously slow when debugging. I'm trying to debug an ASP.Net application and in Chrome developer tools it seems to either be Stalled or be Waiting (TTFB) for Web Api operations for more than 30 seconds at a time that usually take less than a second.

I have tried disabling 'Enabling Diagnostic tools', 'Javascript debugging in ASP.Net' and 'elapsed time PerfTip' but makes no difference.  I have cleared WebCacheFiles and Temporary ASP.Net files as well.

Is it possible it's SQL Server that is stalling? Apologies if my question is very broad, I'm not sure what information is best to provide to be more concise. Please ask for any information helpful to resolve this.

Comment: What updates were installed on what edition and architecture of Windows 10?  What versions of Visual Studio, (ASP).NET, and SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Windows 10 Pro version 1803 64 bit, ASP.Net MVC v4, VS 2017 v15.7.1, SQL Server v17.7

Comment: There is no SQL Server 17.7. Do you mean SSMS 17.7? If so, what version of SQL Server?

Comment: Sorry I do yes. 14.0.1000

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 [v15.7.4](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#15.7.4) is the latest, so I would try updating to that first.

Comment: Will do, its over 2GB so maybe a while before I can confirm it worked

Comment: Make sure the SQL Server service is running. I've had some problems with it not always starting on Windows 10.

Comment: Are you able to use the `Visual Studio Installer` application?  The incremental update downloads are a lot smaller.

Comment: Not always small. I had an update from 15.7.3 to 4 that I remember was really large, way over 1 G, without any web stuff.

Comment: Update made no difference. SQL Service is running otherwise the calls would fail rather than just taking so long. The MVC View loads quickly enough but the web api calls are taking a long time. I noticed windows 10 updates has removed symbols so not sure if this has made a difference

Comment: I now have a colleague having the same issue so its not limited to my machine

Comment: Update: I put a breakpoint on the first line of a call that is triggered and it took 42 seconds for it to hit. The call in question doesn't do any database related code so SQL Server is not the issue. Just got to work out why it took this long between the jquery get call and the web api controller being hit.

Comment: Update 2: Running without debugging does not have the issue so related to debug in some way